# How does the knockout rendering for imagepicker work in SurveyJS Survey Creator

Tags: knockout.js, surveyjs

Can someone help me understand how imagepicker is rendered in knockout SurveyJS Survey Creator?

I am not sure where or how the binding to the elements in the html template occurs or how the html template with the binding targets is fetched and used, nor do I know how/ where the cssClassBuilder is used.
I would also like to know where the render is called.

The html template with the targets of the binding are found here as far as I can tell: https://github.com/surveyjs/survey-library/blob/master/src/knockout/templates/question-imagepicker.html

The knockout imagepicker implementation is found here:
https://github.com/surveyjs/survey-library/blob/95df902245be99b1d2ac649453558e210bf109cb/src/knockout/koquestion_imagepicker.ts#L2

The base imagepicker implementation is found here:
https://github.com/surveyjs/survey-library/blob/95df902245be99b1d2ac649453558e210bf109cb/src/question_imagepicker.ts#L303

The cssClassBuilder is found here:
https://github.com/surveyjs/survey-library/blob/master/src/utils/cssClassBuilder.ts

Comment: I searched the repo for `applyBindings` and you will find what you are searching for: https://github.com/search?q=repo%3Asurveyjs%2Fsurvey-library%20applyBindings&type=code